# How to Compare two variables in Robot Framework if double quotes are present in the string

Tags: robotframework

In my test case i am trying to compare if

> 'Content-type "application/pdf" is not supported'

is present or not.

This the error i am getting :

> Evaluating expression '"Content-type "application/pdf" is not
>   supported" != ""' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (, line
>   1)

My keyword expression is :

```
Run Keyword If  "${failure_message}" != "${EMPTY}"   My Click Element  id=btn_import_cancel
```

Answer (score 4):

Robot allows you to use the variable in the expression without quotes by omitting the braces.

```
run keyword if  $failure_message != "" My Click Element  id=btn_import_cancel
```

For more information, see [Evaluating Expressions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluating%20expressions) in the BuiltIn library documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the variable in triple quotes - in python that's called a string literal, and it can contain almost all characters  without problems - double quotes, `\n`, etc.
Example for your case:

```
Run Keyword  If  """${failure_message}""" != "${EMPTY}"   My Click Element  id=btn_import_cancel 
# ${EMPTY} is a RF builtin variable, shortcut for an empty string - not needed here, but I guess it helps with the case's readability
```

What happened in the original approach is that RF substituted the value of `${failure_message}`, and as it had the double quotes char this effectively closed the enclosing quotes midway - here: `"Content-type "application`
, leaving `{application}` out of the string and "making it" an operand for the the python expression.